# Why can a distance $d =2t+1$ code correct $2t$ errors of known locations?

Tags: error-correction

I intuitively understood why a distance $d = 2t+1$ can correct $2t$ known location errors. Could anyone provide a more rigorous explanation on this?

Comment: A rigorous explanation of this can be seen from the Quantum Error Correction Conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume your error correcting code stores 1 logical qubit. It has logical states $|0_L\rangle$ and $|1_L\rangle$. Now, for any $\sigma$ which is a tensor product of Pauli operators on no more than $2t$ locations, we know that
$$
\langle 0_L|\sigma|1_L\rangle=0
$$
because the smallest operator that maps from 0 to 1 contains at least $2t+1$ terms.

Now, imagine we want to distinguish all the errors on a set of $2t$ qubits. If it is the case that all $\{\sigma_i|0_L\rangle\}$ and $\{\sigma_j|1_L\rangle\}$ are orthogonal, then we'll be able to distinguish which errors have happened, and correct for them. So, let's check orthogonality
$$
\langle 0_L|\sigma_i\sigma_j|1_L\rangle=\langle 0_L|\sigma|1_L\rangle=0
$$
since if $\sigma_i$ and $\sigma_j$ act on the same set of qubits, the product is also an operator on those $2t$ qubits. You can make an identical argument between just the 0 components and just the 1 components with errors.